# Find out which instruction is wrong

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

The object of the following flow-chart is to rearrange the numbers in boxes 1, 2 and 3 in such a fashion that, at the end:

```
Box 3 will always contain the largest number,
Box 1 will always contain the smallest number,
```

However, this flow-chart is INCORRECT.  As it stands, it will not accomplish the desired purpose.

Which one instruction must be changed to correct the flow-chart?
[image]

In order to correct this flow-chart, we must change Instruction No.

So that the first box-number mentioned in it is box-number.............

And the second box-number mentioned in it is box-number.............

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We want to arrange the numbers so that reading down from 1 to 3, they are increasing in size. There is one particular branch which is clearly wrong.

**Which one?**

> Look at the 2 branches coming off step 5.

**I still don't see it**

> The yes branch... does that look a bit strange?

**Nope**

> Step 5's "Yes" branch says "if $box3 < box2$ then end" - we always want $box2 < box3$ so this has to be wrong.

**Wait - so that means the answer is...**

> In order to correct this flow-chart, we must change Instruction No. 5
>  So that the first box-number mentioned in it is box-number 2
>  And the second box-number mentioned in it is box-number 3

Comment: @AeJey just trying to [use spoiler tags a bit more effectively](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1500/2518) :-)

Comment: I liked it. Will try to adopt it in my answers too. Hope it will be okay for you. :)